# How to list AWS RDS instances that are stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I'm trying to use the AWS CLI to list all the AWS RDS instances that I have that are in a Stopped status.

It's possible with EC2 with `aws ec2 describe-instances` and adding a filter `--filters  "Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped"`.

However, with `aws rds describe-db-instances`, I do not find an equivalent. There is a `--filter` option, but only had the following options as filters: db-cluster-id, db-instance-id, dbi-resource-id, domain, engine.

So what AWS CLI command can I use to list all the RDS instances that are currently Stopped (Status=stopped)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--query` instead of `--filters`:

something like:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query '...'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html

Comment: Was hoping for something in the filter, but it does look like the only solution is with a query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[].DBInstanceStatus[]'
```

output:

```
[
   "available"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command helps in listing detailed info on RDS.

aws rds describe-db-instances --output text --query 'DBInstances[].[DBInstanceIdentifier, DBInstanceClass, Engine, DBInstanceStatus, InstanceCreateTime, MultiAZ, EngineVersion, PubliclyAccessible, StorageType, DeletionProtection]' > RDS-Inv.csv

Comment: Please improve the style of your answer.